# How to use bitmask in c++?

Tags: c++, bitmask

I'm tryin to mask an address in c++. This is what i've tried.

```
INT32 * myaddr = (INT32*)addr; // This converted 'addr' to the hexadecimal format -- 'myaddr'
```

Now how do I `and` it 0xff00 ?

```
UINT32 sec_addr = (myaddr & 0xff);
```

When I try to do the following..
This is the error I get:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘LEVEL_BASE::INT32*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator&’
```

What is the mistake i'm doing?

Comment: the mistake is you're `and`ing a `INT32*` with a `int`

Comment: Also, `0xff` is not equal to `0xff00` but rather to `0x00ff` (maybe its just a typo in your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are operating a pointer with an integer. Use the original `addr` variable, which is an integer, instead of `myaddr`:

`UINT32 sec_addr = addr & 0xff;  // according to your question, this should be 0xFF00`

BTW: your first line:

```
INT32 * myaddr = (INT32*)addr; // This converted 'addr' to the hexadecimal format -- 'myaddr'
```

doesn't convert `addr` into "hexadecimal format". Hexadecimal is just a way to represent the number when you print it. Both `addr` and `myaddr` can be showed into whatever numeric base you want.

`printf ("%d %X\n", addr, addr);`

prints the value of `addr` in both decimal and hexadecimal format.

Comment: I don't think that's the case:
`addr: 140737488345600`
`sec_addr: 0`
How can the sec_addr be 0?

Comment: My bad. I & with 255 then. now with 0xff00. :)

Comment: `140737488345600` is `7FFFFFFFDA00` in hex.

`7FFFFFFFDA00 & 0000000000FF = 000000000000`

Comment: I've a problem that I can't convert from uint32 to void*

invalid conversion from ‘LEVEL_BASE::UINT32’ to ‘const LEVEL_BASE::VOID*’

Here is my code:
 UINT32 sec_addr_main = addr & 0xff00;
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
  UINT32 sec_addr = sec_addr_main + 64*i;

Answer (score 0):

First line should be

```
INT32 myaddr = (INT32)addr;
```

Assuming you are on a 32-bit platform.